# How do I access a contract class variable from an extern “C” function "void apply()"?

Tags: smart-contract

In some scenarios, It's convenient to configure the conditions for monitoring some certain transactions by using this method

> ```
> extern "C" {
>     void apply(uint64_t receiver, uint64_t code, uint64_t action) {
>         if(code==receiver)
>         {
>             switch(action)
>             {
>                 EOSIO_DISPATCH_HELPER( token, (transfer))
>             }
>         }else if (code=="eosio.token"_n.value){
>             execute_action( name(receiver), name(code), &token::invite);
>         }
>     }
> };
> ```

Is there any methods to change the condition like "eosio.token" in this code dynamically ?
Maybe It's a basic cpp programming problem. but i have failed to find the solution from the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access contract-level variables from within *extern "C" { void apply(..) }"* which is a dispatcher-function and *external* - executed in a different scope/context than functions on contract-level.